# Adding/Subtracting two editText fields together

Tags: android

Okay I've searched far and wide for ways on doing this and in my head it seemed so simple but when I've come to write the code for my idea I just have drawn a blank.

I've got two edit text fields and with Number input only on them. I wish to subtract the number from one of the editText views from the other and place it into a normal Text view.

I wish for the TextView to update immediately after both EditText views have been filled with a number.

Does anyone have an Idea how this could be accomplished?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int iEditWages;
int iEditMoneySpent;
String sEditWages;
String sEditMoneySpent;
String tTotalLeftToSpend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalWagesNumber);
    EditText EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalSpentNumber);
    TextView TotalLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalViewNumber);

    sEditWages = EditWages.getText().toString();
    sEditMoneySpent = EditMoneySpent.getText().toString();

    iEditWages = Integer.parseInt(sEditWages);
    iEditMoneySpent = Integer.parseInt(sEditMoneySpent);

    int Subtract = iEditWages - iEditMoneySpent;

    tTotalLeftToSpend = String.valueOf(Subtract);

    TotalLeft.setText(tTotalLeftToSpend);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to get it working. It was a combination of the Text watcher examples left by the users and also the converting strings to integers and subtracting them the way that Nambi provided me. Here is my final, and WORKING code! :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

int iEditWages;
int iEditMoneySpent;
int iSubtract;
String sEditWages;
String sEditMoneySpent;
String sTotalLeftToSpend;
EditText EditWages;
EditText EditMoneySpent;
TextView TotalLeft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalSpentNumber);
    EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalWagesNumber);
    EditMoneySpent.addTextChangedListener(this);
    EditWages.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalWagesNumber);
    EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalSpentNumber);
    TotalLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalViewNumber);

    sEditWages = EditWages.getText().toString();
    sEditMoneySpent = EditMoneySpent.getText().toString();
    try {
        iEditWages = Integer.parseInt(sEditWages);
        iEditMoneySpent = Integer.parseInt(sEditMoneySpent);
        iSubtract = iEditWages - iEditMoneySpent;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    sTotalLeftToSpend = String.valueOf(iSubtract);
    TotalLeft.setText(sTotalLeftToSpend);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have two edittext in your xml layout like editText1,editText2

```
EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

EditText editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

then you need to get the value in String and then convert into Integer

```
 String  s1=editText1.getText.toString();

            String s2=editText1.getText.toString();
```

make sure for **NumberFormatException** here

```
      int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);

        int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);

        int subtract=i1-i2;
```

Convert the Integer into String to print it in TextView

```
 String s=String.valueof(subtract);

        Textview1.setText(s);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and answer. On paper this has no errors and in my head (Although not too experienced head) This looks like it should work. I've implemented it and at first crashed my app a couple of times but I figured out why it crashed and now the only problem is that it does not Update the textView even though I have added the setText statement at the bottom.

Comment: what exception occured at your logcat.

Comment: 12-12 04:35:46.450: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1158): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

12-12 04:39:03.500: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1158): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

They were the only log cat results highlighted and they were highlighted in orange.

Comment: did you changed the String to Integer before setText.

Comment: Yep I used the String s=String.valueOf(Subtract) then TextView.SetText(s) (Obviously I added my own string names that I used :P)

Comment: Okay added it to my first post :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `TextWatcherListener`:

```
private class Watcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String str = String.valueOf(editable);
        EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        String edit2Text = edit2.getText();
        if(!"".equals(str) && !"".equals(edit2Text)){
             int result = Integer.parseInt(str) - Inetegr.parseInt(edit2Text);
             TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
             tv.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
}

EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
edit1.addTextChandegListener(new Watcher());
```

you should write something like this . . .

everytime when the text changes in one `editText` it will automatically get second `editText`-s text, will make some calculations and saves it in `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use text watcher on both of your edit text boxes if no order is defined( user can fill any edit text box first) otherwise use text watcher on second edit text box. 

Here is sample. Hope it will help you

EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewByID(R.id.textView1);

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{               
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
   {
   }
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
   {
   }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
   {
     if(editText2.getText().toString().trim().length>0)
      {         
         int a= Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString().trim());
         int b= Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString().trim());
     tv.settext("REsult "+a-b);
      }
}
```

});

Hope it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: y 2 ans for same question..you can put both as one ans..Solution 1 and solution 2

Comment: yeah, agree, but I posted second answer when Leccles1 updated his question with code so according to the variable he declared and his need and requirement, I have posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code with this

```
       package com.app.helpproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int iEditWages;
    int iEditMoneySpent;
    String sEditWages;
    String sEditMoneySpent;
    String tTotalLeftToSpend;
    EditText EditWages;
    EditText EditMoneySpent;
    TextView TotalLeft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TotalLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        EditMoneySpent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
            {
                if (EditWages.getText().toString().trim().length()== 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Wages First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
                if (EditWages.getText().toString().trim().length()!= 0 && EditMoneySpent.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
                {
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(EditWages.getText().toString().trim());
                    int b = Integer.parseInt(EditMoneySpent.getText().toString().trim());
                    int c=a-b;
                    TotalLeft.setText("Result " + c);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, there were a lot of errors I needed to fix but once I got the code to run without any errors it still didn't work unfortunately. Once I entered the wages I tried to put a number in the Total spent and it crashed the app :/

Comment: please try the updated code. Change id of your editText and textView in the code accordingly